# Location based push notifications with MobileFirst

Tags: mobile, push-notification, location, ibm-mobilefirst

We are trying to send push notifications to user based on user's location, for eg when user reaches near a location he/she will get a notification from the application, we are currently using Mobilefirst 8.0.

Comment: How do you make the server aware of the client's location? Will you be calling an adapter ? Trying to see if you are looking for local notifications or server dispatched notifications

Comment: We are looking for server dispatched push notifications by Mobilefirst server

Comment: Yes, we are using Java adapters

Answer (score 0):

I would adopt a solution like this:

1. When the location plugin has detected that the user is in a specific location or zone, it fires.
2. Within the action ( success callback), call a MFP adapter with all the relevant information.
3. This adapter can either call the MFP Push service REST endpoints directly. The invocation looks [this](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#rest-apis).

OR

4. The adapter calls a backend, that will invoke the Push service REST endpoints. This will give more flexibility in terms of pushing customized payload , that can change according to business cases ( eg: festivals,discounts).

The complete list of Push service REST endpoints are [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/api/rest/push-apis/).